# Creating Mutations In Nestjs Using The Code First approach

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am in the process of creating a graphql api that is built on Nestjs (code first approach) and prisma for the database management. I have followed nestjs' official page and have successfully created the resolver for housing my queries, subscriptions and mutations. My first Query is working correctly without any problems. However after creating a mutation, the created mutation don't prompt for any parameters and the graphql playground does not indicate errors in my mutation request. 
This mutation is responsible for creating a user and is supposed to take two parameters for the successful completion of the operation.

i have tried re-creating the mutation using the schema first approach but the app crashes during start up. I also tried adding a name property to the mutation but still nothing happens.

This is my mutation

```
@Mutation(returns => User, { name: 'createUser' })
  async createUser(args) {
    return await this.userService.createUser(args);
  }
```

and in the user service

```
  async create(args) {
    return await this.prismah.mutation.createUser({
      name: args.name,
      email: args.email,
    });
  }
```

the mutation should prompt for two parameters before submision and after submision it should create a user instance in the db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i created a class UserInput like

```
import { InputType, Field } from 'type-graphql';

@InputType()
export class UserInput {
  @Field() name: string;
  @Field() email: string;
}
```

and changed my resolver to look like

```
import {Args} from '@nestjs/graphql';
import {UserInput} from './path-to-the-user-input-class-created';


@Mutation(returns => User, { name: 'createUser' })
  async createUser(@Args('data') user: UserInput) {
    return await this.userService.createUser(user);
  }
```

with this changes, my mutation is now working as expected. it prompts for the required variables and the submission process is completed.

Comment: What is the "User" variable?